# How to get product row from each order of child table list using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have two model entities:

```
public class Order
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Guid OrderGuid { get; set; }
        public string CustomOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
        public Guid OrderItemGuid { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int Sno { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int SKUId { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductSKU ProductSKU { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get each order with particular product name row from order items.

For example, suppose data in an order,orderitms has 5 product records.

and assume that in that product name is abc having 2 records.

For the 2nd order, order items has 3 records, and one of those as `abc` product name.

I want get order list with orderitems of `abc` only ... bellow i tried way there. in that I'm getting total orderitems

Please help me ?

I tried like this:

```
List<Contracts.Entities.Order> orders = DbSet.Include(t => t.OrderItems).ToList();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ProductName))
{
    List<OrderItem> orderItems = orders.SelectMany(t => t.OrderItems).Where(t => t.ProductName == request.ProductName).ToList();
    orders = orderItems.Select(t => t.Order).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `DbSet.Include(t => t.OrderItems).ToList();` - don't do this; it downloads the entire order/items database into the client

Comment: You haven't really explained your problem very well. Are you saying that you want all orders, whether they have an ABC product or not, and if they do have an ABC then you want the orderitem too, but only if it's ABC? It means when you have a million orders in your DB and 100 of them have ABC, you will get: 1 million orders, 999900 of them will have 0 items in their OrderItems, and 100 of them will have 1+ items in their OrderItems, right?

Answer (score 1):

So every OrderItem has a ProductName, and you want (several properties of) all Orders that have at least one OrderItem with this ProductName.

```
string productName = ...
var ordersWithProductName = dbContext.Orders.GroupJoin  
    dbContext.OrderItems,             // GroupJoin Orders with OrderItems
    order => order.OrderId            // from every Order take the primary key
    orderItem => orderItem.OrderId,   // from every OrderItem take the foreign key

    // parameter ResultSelector: 
    // take each Order with all its zero or more OrderItems to make one new object
    (order, orderItemsOfThisOrder) => new
    {
        // Select only the Order properties that you plan to use:
        Id = order.OrderId,
        UserId = order.UserId,
        ...

        Items = orderItemsOfThisOrder.Select(orderItem => new
        {
            Id = orderItem.OrderItemId,
            ProductName = orderItem.ProductName,
            ...

            // not needed, you know the value:
            // OrderId = orderItem.OrderId
        })
        .ToList(),
    })

    // keep only those Orders that have at least one OrderItem with productName
    .Where(order => order.Items
                         .Where(orderItem => orderItem.ProductName == productName)
                         .Any());
```

This way, you get all Orders, each with all its OrderItems, that have at least one OrderItem that has a ProductName equal to productName.

In entity framework you don't have to GroupJoin yourself, you can use the virtual ICollection instead. I'm not sure if ef-core supports this:

```
    var ordersWithProductName = dbContext.Orders.Select(order => new
    {
        // Select only the Order properties that you plan to use:
        Id = order.OrderId,
        UserId = order.UserId,
        ...

        Items = order.OrderItems.Select(orderItem => new
        {
            Id = orderItem.OrderItemId,
            ProductName = orderItem.ProductName,
            ...

            // not needed, you know the value:
            // OrderId = orderItem.OrderId
        })
        .ToList(),
    })

    // keep only those Orders that have at least on OrderItem with productName
    .Where(order => order.Items
                         .Where(orderItem => orderItem.ProductName == productName)
                         .Any());
```

One final remark: are you sure that property `Order.OrderItems` is a List? Does Order.OrderItems[4] have a defined meaning? Shouldn't it be an `ICollection<OrderItem>`?

Comment: yes  its IList<OrderItem>.  and the same result I'm getting  with what u said above logic with multiple order items (not particulat product name)

Comment: So does Order.OrderItems[4] has a defined meaning? When you execute the query, it is unspecified which element is put on index [4] and which one is on index [3], unless you sort all your queries. This might be a waste of processing power, because in most queries you are not interested in sorted OrderItems. It is not for nothing that Entity Framework usually has an ICollection instead of IList.

Comment: *I'm not sure if ef-core supports this* - it supports building queries from using nav properties, sure.. and filtered includes too, if it's recent

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
List<Contracts.Entities.Order> orders = DbSet.Order.Include(t => t.OrderItems).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ProductName))
        {
            orders = orders.Where(r => r.OrderItems.Any(rc => rc.ProductName == request.ProductName)).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Download every order and associated item in the database? Er..